# Generics and wildcard in Java for Futures Task

Tags: java, multithreading, generics, concurrent.futures

```
public class SOQuestion {
private class TaskResult1 {//some pojo  
}

private class TaskResult2{// some other pojo 
}

private class Task1 implements Callable<TaskResult1> {
    public TaskResult1 call() throws InterruptedException {
        // do something...
        return new TaskResult1();
    }
}

private class Task2 implements Callable<TaskResult2> {
    public TaskResult2 call() throws InterruptedException {
        // do something else...
        return new TaskResult2();
    }
}

private void cancelFuturesTask1(List<Future<TaskResult1>> futureList ){
    for(Future<TaskResult1> future: futureList){
        if(future.isDone())
        {
            continue;
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("cancelling futures.....Task1.");
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}

private void cancelFuturesTask2(List<Future<TaskResult2>> futureList ){
    for(Future<TaskResult2> future: futureList){
        if(future.isDone())
        {
            continue;
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("cancelling futures.....Task2.");
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}

void runTasks() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    CompletionService<TaskResult1> completionService1 = new ExecutorCompletionService<TaskResult1>(executor);
    List<Future<TaskResult1>> futuresList1 = new ArrayList<Future<TaskResult1>>();

    for (int i =0 ;i<10; i++) {
        futuresList1.add(completionService1.submit(new Task1()));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
        try {
            Future<TaskResult1> f = completionService1.take();
            System.out.print(f.get());
            System.out.println("....Completed..first one.. cancelling all others.");    
            cancelFuturesTask1(futuresList1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught interrruption....");
            break;
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            System.out.println("Cancellation execution....");
            break;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Execution exception....");
            break;
        }
    }


    CompletionService<TaskResult2> completionService2 = new ExecutorCompletionService<TaskResult2>(executor);
    List<Future<TaskResult2>> futuresList2 = new ArrayList<Future<TaskResult2>>();
    try{
        for (int i =0 ;i<10; i++) {
            futuresList2.add(completionService2.submit(new Task2()));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
            try {
                Future<TaskResult2> f = completionService2.take();
                System.out.print(f.get());
                System.out.println("....Completed..first one.. cancelling all others.");    
                cancelFuturesTask2(futuresList2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Caught interrruption....");
                break;
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                System.out.println("Cancellation execution....");
                break;
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                System.out.println("Execution exception....");
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    executor.shutdown();
}
}
```

As seen in the example, there is some repetition. I want to use Generics and wild card to generalize objects and re-use some methods.

My specific ask would be "cancelFuturesTask1" and "cancelFuturesTask2". Both methods do the same thing. How can I generalize them?
I read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

I created a base class "TaskResult" extended "TaskResult1" and "TaskResult2"

```
private class TaskResult1 extends TaskResult
private class TaskResult2 extends TaskResult
```

and then use

```
List<Futures<? extends TaskResult>>
```

It gives me complication error and I am having some confusion in extending the concept to `List<Futures<?>>` in this case.
Any pointers or explanation on how to do that will help here.

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need some clarification.

Comment: Since `cancel()` only depends on the Future, why care what parametrizes it?  `List<Future<?>>`

Comment: There is a raw type warning and type cast error from the caller.              cancelFuturesTask1(futuresList1);

Answer (score 1):

This compiles fine for me, let me know if you get errors on it also.

```
public class FutureTest
{

   public void cancelAll( Future<?> ... futures ) {
      for( Future<?> f : futures ) {
         if( !f.isDone() ) {
            Logger.getLogger(FutureTest.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.INFO, "Canceling {0}", f);
            f.cancel(true);
         }
      }
   }

   public <T extends Task1 & Task2> void cancelAll( List<Future<T>> futures ) {
      cancelAll( futures.toArray( new Future[futures.size()]) );
   }
}

interface Task1 {}
interface Task2 {}
```

For a more specific type, see my second method.  You can do it with a Generic Method and Bounded Type Parameter, but only if all but one type are interfaces.  Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so you can't write one method that takes multiple (not covariant) class types.  That's why I think unbounded (wildcard, "`<?>`") methods like the first example are better here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html

Comment: I get the following error .. "The method cancelFuturesTask1(Future<?>...) in the type SOQuestion is not applicable for the arguments (List<Future<SOQuestion.TaskResult1>>)"

Comment: @Kunal That's... 'cause it's not a List.

Comment: thanks I was not familiar with ... syntax, when I do "             cancelFuturesTask1(futuresList1.toArray(new Future[futuresList1.size()]));
" it works fine. No compilation errors or warnings. But what if I wanted to use typed Generics?

Comment: @Kunal See my edit.  Unfortunately in Java this only works for interfaces, not classes.